# Inaccurate flow rate measurements of an engine diesel fuel due to change of its viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, temperature, flow, measurements, viscosity

I am measuring the volumetric flow rate of a diesel fuel using "Turbines" [flow meter](https://www.gilsoneng.com/WebCat6/pdf/TI_datasheet_TM_Series.pdf), both in the supply and return fuel lines of an industrial diesel engine ([Caterpillar 3512B](https://www.cat.com/en_US/products/new/power-systems/industrial/industrial-diesel-engines/18398034.html) – coupled with a generator for power production), in an attempt to measure the total fuel consumption by the engine. However, the fuel temperature in the return line is higher than the fuel temperature in the supply line, thus, the viscosity of the return fuel is lower than the viscosity of the supply fuel. Due to this change in fuel viscosity, I obtain erroneous flow rate measurements.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to compensate for the temperature or viscosity change of the diesel fuel in order to obtain accurate volumetric flow rate measurements.

Thank you for any idea you could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key parameter is probably not viscosity but *density*. You need a *true mass fuel flow meter* as used in jet aircraft. These run on "diesel" too (or something very much like it) and the temperature ranges of operation in this application are severe.

So the true mass fuel flow meter was invented to accomodate this. Inside the meter is a vane protruding into the flow. More dense fuel pushes harder on the vane than less dense fuel, and fast-flowing fuel pushes harder on the vane than slow-flowing fuel. the vane is usually shaped like a propeller but instead of spinning freely, the "vane" experiences a *torque* that is due to the speed AND the density of the fuel, and the meter system measures that torque and converts it into pounds (mass) of fuel flow per minute.

Comment: Thank you for your help.